# Probability theory, to prove uniqueness

Tags: probability-theory

Let (Ω,F,P) be a probability space and let A1,A2,...be independent events in F.  LetX: Ω→R be a random variable (withσ-algebras F and B), which is also a random variablewhen Ω is equipped with theσ-algebraσ({An,An+1,...}),  for everyn∈N.  Prove that there is aunique x∈Rsuch thatP({X=x}) = 1.

Since by Kolmogoro law, we have A ∈ ∩ σ(A1,A2,...,An), P(A) is either 0 or 1. Then I am wondering how to prove its uniqueness.

Comment: Use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) please.

Answer (score 0):

$(X\leq y)$ belongs to the tail sigma algebra. Hence $P(X \leq y)=0$ or $1$ for every $y$. Consider $x=\sup \{y: P(X \leq y)=0\}$. Then $P(x\leq y)=0$ for all $y <x$ and $P(x\leq y)=1$ for all $y>x$. Can you now show that $P(X=x)=1$?

[$P(X=x)=\lim_{n \to \infty} [P(X\leq x+\frac 1n )-P(X \leq x-\frac  1n)]$].

Uniqueness is obvious: If $P(X=x)=1$ and $P(X=y)=1$ then $X=x=y$ with probability $1$ so $x=y$.

Comment: I understand now, but how to prove there is a unique x?

Comment: If $P(X=x)=1$ and $P(X=y)=1$ then $P(x=y)=1$ which means $x=y$. @jiayiyu

Comment: Oh, I got it! Thank you!